# Can anyone please let me know if there is any limit of users to be added in SPO list alerts?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Can we add 5000-6000 users in Share point online list alert?
If yes, is there a feasible way to add them?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear limit on the number of people that can be added to the SharePoint list alert. So, you can add 5000 users on SharePoint Online list alert.

However, It's a tough job to add 5000 users.

Pay attention that in OOB alert settings, the emails you specify have to be from users in the system (your organization).

You may think about using a workflow to create a alert. You just need to add the 5000 users to one or more groups. When somethings changed, send an email to the designated group.